# why I am getting zoomed image in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using image viewer in angular js .I am successfully implement the image viewer .I didn't get actual image but get zoomed image why ?

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/eemTIHAON9T6nXf31D8C?p=preview

**Getting This output (Zoomed image)**

[image]

**Expecting full image without zoomed**

[image]

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

```
 $scope.ca='https://evportal.airtel.com/sharedimages/Postpaid/93c4e50b-10a7-4717-b976-592b74bc2d371541256937292_poa_front_image.jpeg'

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the resetImage() function in app.js you set the currentScale to 1. The image will then be drawn with a 1:1 scale on the canvas. 
You don't want this, because this way the image will be drawn depending on it's own width/height on the canvas. Big pictures will appear zoomed in, and small pictures will appear zoomed out.

Instead you want initialize a scale depending on the width/height of the input source so the entire picture will be drawn on the canvas. A neat way to do this is like this:

```
currentScale = Math.min(canvas.width/image.width, canvas.height/image.height);
```

Comment: but it is not centered

Comment: Replace drawImage on line 193 and remove the translate line should do the trick. Here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/eJdq4twcU8dSKuTCYfPz?p=preview

Comment: thanks for answering but it break "clockwise" and "anticlockwise" direction ..please check click any of button

Comment: that's because your rotation function is rotating the image around the (0,0) coordinates. You need to translate the picture so it's center will be on (0,0), then rotate, and then translate the picture back

Comment: colud you please help me reolving this issue

Comment: please update the pluker please i am not able to do that from morning

Comment: please help here

Comment: please answer this question

Comment: sorry i have no time to look into it right now, i will get back on this

Comment: please look into this issue whenever you get time .I am frustated from this issue

Comment: did you get time.please have a look

Comment: thanks a lot ..can you please tell me if whta you did if you have few min

Comment: As i said you had to translate the picture to the center, then translate it back. It's done on line 191

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scale parameter for image. According to the give plunker link, in app.js file see line no. 92 , You need to replace `currentScale = 1;` by

```
currentScale = 0.1;
```

This will render your image as you expected.

To see the working example follow the link below.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7bvAr?p=preview

Comment: but it is not centered